# Best way to parallelize a big linked list

Tags: c, parallel-processing, linked-list

I dont have any experience with parallelism. So, if you could help me it would be really amazing.

I developed a code in C and this part of the code takes 99% of the execution time.

h is a linked list, a really long linked list.

```
    g = h;
    while(g != NULL){
        f = g->next;
        t = g;
        while(f != NULL){
            if(SomeFastBooleanFunction(g, f)){
                fastMergeInformationsInG(g,f);
                t->next = f->next;
                free(f);
                f = t->next;
            }
            else{
                t = f;
                f = f->next;
            }
        }
      g = g->next;
     }
```

The biggest problem here is the lenght of the linked list that is really big (approximated n!2^{binomial{n}{2}} and n >= 9). Any ideas are wellcome.

Thanks a lot.

------------ UPDATE -----------------

I will put here the real code used. The function above is the cleanIso bellow. I didn't put the checkIso funcion, but this function is a optimized function that check is f is isomorphic to g.

```
    struct Graph{                                                                                                                                                                                               
        SomeInfo
        int *edges;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        struct Graph *next;                                                                                                                                                                                       
    };

    graph *cleanIso(graph *g){
        graph *f1, *f2, *f3;
        f1 = g;
        while(f1 != NULL){
            f2 = f1;
            f3 = f1->next;
            while(f3 != NULL){
            if(checkColorIso(f1, f3)){
                f1->nHom += f3->nHom;
                f2->next = f3->next;
                free(f3->edges);
                free(f3);
                f3 = f2->next;
            }
            else{
                f2 = f3;
                f3 = f3->next;
            }
        }
        f1 = f1->next;
     }

     return g;
  }

    int checkColorIso(graph *g, graph *f){                                                                                                                                                             
        graph *h;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        int r = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                
        int v[3] = {1, 2, 3};                                                                                                                                                                                     
        int nP = g->size*(g->size - 1)/2;                                                                                                                                                                         
        int a[3], b[3];                                                                                                                                                                                           
        //Initializing
        a[0] = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        a[1] = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        a[2] = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        b[0] = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        b[1] = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        b[2] = 0;
        //It just check if it there is some color bijection that maybe produce a isormophism                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        for(int i = 0; i < g->size*(g->size - 1)/2; i++){                                                                                                                                                         
            a[g->edges[i]-1]++;                                                                                                                                                                                     
            b[f->edges[i]-1]++;                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        do{                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            if(a[0] == b[v[0]-1] && a[1] == b[v[1]-1] && a[2] == b[v[2]-1]){                                                                                                                                        
                r++;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }while(std::next_permutation(v, v+3));                                                                                                                                                                    
        if(r == 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                
            return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        r = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        h = initializeGraph(g->size, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                       
        do{                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            copyGraph(f, h);                                                                                                                                                                                        
            for(int i = 0; i < nP; i++)                                                                                                                                                                             
                h->edges[i] = v[h->edges[i] - 1];                                                                                                                                                                     
            r = checkIso(g, h);
     }while(std::next_permutation(v, v+3) && r == 0);                                                                                                                                                          
     free(h->edges);                                                                                                                                                                                           
     free(h);                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     return r;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }
```

Comment: Of the code shown, how much relative time does `fastMergeInformationsInG` take? (And probably the same question for SomeFastBooleanFunction.) Are those function(s) easy to optimise?

Comment: SomeFasBooleanFunction is fast on this case(since n is small) but the problem is NP-Comple. To tell the truth this function verify if a graph g and a graph f are isomorphic and has complexity O(2^n), but n is at most 15, so is fast. But this function is not easy to optimize because this problem is NP-Complete. On the other hand, the function Merge has a constant time.

Comment: if `SomeFastBooleanFunction()` can be used to impose an order, the program can be changed from O(N*N) to O (n log N), or better. But without details, there is nothing to optimize.

Comment: Now I added the almost entired code. The checkIso is missing but, this function is really long. :)

Comment: The simplest parallelisation is to compute the six permutations separately. This will also simplify the checkColorIso() function, and enable you to remove the silly (IMO) C++ stuff, and the reallocation (sic!) in the compare function. (but permuting the colors into a *canonical* form would reduce the complexity by an equal factor)

Comment: `a[g->edges[i]-1]++;`This implies that `g->edges[ i ]` can only contain values {1,2,3} That doesn't make sense to me. And: if it is actually an unordered list of (unique) edge numbers why not just keep it sorted and use memcmp() (plus maybe even hash it)